# How to set price in proper format in email template in magento-2.2.7?

Tags: magento2.2.7

I am using magento-2.2.7. In email template, price subtotal and grandtotal is showing like that 0.5000000000045 .How to change this price in proper format. Please help me to solve it. I want to share screenshot as follow :
https://paste.pics/67A5H

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code**

```
protected $priceHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper
) {
    $this->priceHelper = $priceHelper;
}

public function getFormattedPrice($price)
{
    return $this->priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
}
```

**Using Object Manager [Not Recommended way]**

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
    $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); // Instance of Pricing Helper
    $price =  1000; //Your Price
    $formattedPrice = $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
?>
```

**Hope It helps.**

Comment: on which file  @Mohit Rane ?

Comment: you can write this code in your block and call the function where you want to use

Comment: I want to use in order email template.

Comment: which block module_sales block or module_email block ??

Comment: is this your custom email template and are you using any module?

Comment: i will override code for view/frontend only for email template.

Comment: is it order email?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96587/discussion-between-mohit-rane-and-lovely-setia).

Comment: I didn't find any solution yet. Please guide me to solve it..

Comment: if you could find out where this `Items Total` is coming, you can solve this issue in no time.

Comment: this Item total is coming from totals.php,

Comment: you can add above-answered code in that `totals.php` file and call that method in phtml file

Comment: I will added this code,but is show some errors during  compilation.

Comment: share a screenshot of error

Comment: this is the screenshot of error https://paste.pics/6BFRQ